# Cesium - Modify infobox contents

Tags: cesiumjs

I have *n* polygons with ids "*test-1-1*", "*test-1-2*" .... "*test-1-n*" which represent a single logical entity. Format of id can be generalized as *< entity_name>-< entity_id>-< i>*, where i is added to distinguish ids of multiple polygons.

My query here is, I want to display only "test" when any of these polygons is clicked. Currently id of selected polygon is displayed in info-box.

Is there any cesium way to do this? I would not prefer manipulating the strings at runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Cesium [Entity](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/Entity.html) has three fields of interest to the `InfoBox` (the thing that pops up when an Entity is selected).

- `entity.id` - Each entity in a dataSource is required to have a unique `id` (a GUID will be auto-generated if no ID is supplied at creation).  It is an arbitrary string and does not need to be human-friendly.
- `entity.name` - This is the human-friendly name of the Entity.  It does *not* need to be unique, you may have as many duplicate names as you like.  It is half a line or less of plain text (not HTML).
- `entity.description` - This is a sandboxed HTML description of the entity, and can span multiple paragraphs or include tables and other styling.

The `InfoBox` will attempt to show `entity.name` on its title bar by default, and will only fall back to show `entity.id` in the title bar if `name` is missing (because `name` is optional, `id` is not).

The body of the `InfoBox` only appears below the title bar if `entity.description` is set (otherwise only the bar is shown).  The description is rendered with a [sandboxed iframe](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/) (to offer some resistance to cross-site scripting for apps that display user-supplied entity descriptions).

> I have n polygons with ids "test-1-1", "test-1-2" .... "test-1-n" ...

For this case, I would keep the existing ids, and set `name` to be the string you wish to see in the InfoBox popup.  Multiple entities can have the same `name` but not the same `id`.